# nginx /phpmyadmin does not redirect to /phpmyadmin/index.php

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-16.04

This is probably just obvious, but I can't figure out why my nginx gives me a 404 error when I try to view it under www.mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin. But www.mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin/index.php works (however I can't log in with this it just redirect to www.mywebsite.com/index.php when I click "go"). Im using ubuntu 16.04.

my nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
worker_connections 768;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript 
text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

my default site file

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /root/Stuffmaker/Website/certificates/www.stuffmaker.website_ssl_certificate.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /root/Stuffmaker/Website/certificates/www.stuffmaker.website_private_key.key;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name my.website;

    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
    location /images {
    try_files $uri =404;
    }
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5050;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: This `location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5050;` will send any requests outside of `/phpmyadmin` to `http://localhost:5050`. You have not posted what `http://localhost:5050` does with it.

Comment: The root for `/phpmyadmin/index.php` is `/usr/share/nginx/html/`, but the root for `/phpmyadmin` is `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`. Where are the files for `phpmyadmin` actually located?

Comment: `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` redirects to `/usr/share/nginx/html/phpmyadmin` had it working like this on another machine and just copied it. And yes, the folders do actually exist :D.